# 64bit printer driver on 32bit Windows server

Tags: windows-server-2003, shared-printers

I'm attempting to add a 64bit driver to a 32bit windows 2003 server, each time I get the below prompt, I locate the disk image from the network and hit ok, but nothing is copied and this is displayed again.

I'm doing this through additional drivers and the drivers section
 (right clicking printers etc)

[image]

Comment: You know that Windows 2k3 is over six years past mainstream EOL and over a year past extended EOL, correct? You really, really should not be using this operating system. Whatever OS you replace it with will be 64-bit and you won't have this problem.

Comment: Thanks, im in the middle of a desktop and server roll out, unfortunately the desktops are being done first, which means the printers on existing servers must have a 64bit print driver.

Answer (score 3):

No. Absolutely not. Will not work.